# What all things the startapp done in Django?

Tags: python, django

When we use :

```
django-admin startapp app_one
```

whats the things the django done for us?

Because I want to know whether we can delete the app directory directly.

[image]

I am not sure whether all the app related data are deleted (Because I don't know the all the `django-admin startapp` things).

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: yes you can delete it.

Comment: This command only creates a necessary folders and files structure. You can safely remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read in the [docs startapp](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#startapp)

> Creates a Django app directory structure for the given app name in the current directory or the given destination.

and also you can look [on the templates](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/conf/app_template/)

so if you never use the code, you can feel free to delete it.